# Replace HTML content in gridview with Linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I want to replace content in a column of my gridview (containing Textbox) with Linkbutton. Indeed, this column contains HTML pages. And I would like to open new windows with these pages HTML interprated when I clik on the Linkbuttons.

For the moment I have only this :

```
<asp: TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Data" Text='<%#Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Data"))) %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" Text='<%#Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Data"))) %>' />
  </EditTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Can someone explain to me how I can proceed please ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("DATA") %>' />
```

in your `ItemTemplate` instead of the `TextBox`

**Edit :**

Make your `NavigateURL="javascript:OpenWindow(MY HTML)"` // You can use Eval to get your HTML as string content on databinding.

**Javascript :**

```
OpenWindow(myHTML)
{
    newwindow=window.open();
    newdocument=newwindow.document;
    newdocument.write(myHTML);
}
```

For more information check out this reference : [JavaScript Dynamic Document Creation in New Windows](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/javascript-dynamic-document-creation-in-new-windows.html)

**EDIT :**

My mistake :), replace the `NavigateUrl` with `OnClientClick` so it becomes like this :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClientClick="javascript:OpenWindow('<%#Eval("MyFieldName") %>');return false;" />
```

or instead of using LinkButton use the anchor  tag :

```
<a href="javascript:OpenWindow('<%#Eval("MyFieldName") %>');" runat="server" id="myLink" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers but it still doesn't work. I clarify that I don't have URLs in this column, but only HTML content. And I would like to open a window with this HTML interpreted.

Comment: Ohh okay :) now i get it :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Siraj ! I put the Javascript function into the site.master file and my Default.aspx page looks like :

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Click" NavigateUrl="javascript:OpenWindow(MY HTML)" />
    </ItemTemplate>

That's what you meant ?

Comment: That would do the trick for sure :) .. Try putting your javascript in the same page (Default.aspx) its better, because its not a global script that you would need of the scope of the whole website

Comment: I tried to put the script like below and I don't understand why it doesn't work :(
More over how can I pass the HTML content into OpenWindow(MY HTML)?
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
   <ItemTemplate> 
       <script type="text/javascript" >
           function OpenWindow(myHTML) {
                 newwindow = window.open();
                 newdocument = newwindow.document;
                 newdocument.write(myHTML);
            }
        </script>   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click" NavigateUrl="javascript:OpenWindow(<html>test</html>)" />
    </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the LinkButton "Click" ... Even if in the function OpenWindow(), I only open a simple alert box. Can you please help me ? Thanks !

Comment: 1st : Place your javascript (<script type="text/javascript" > .... </scirpt>) in the header of your document, and not inside the itemtemplate. 

2nd: Your linkbutton should be like this :
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click" NavigateUrl="javascript:OpenWindow('<%#Eval("MyFieldName") %>');" />

Where my field name is the the property or the fieldname of your datasource containing the HTML you want.
This should work if you do it right.

Comment: I exactly did what you wrote and I have the following error message : "The server tag is not well formed". Moreover an information message explains that the attibute NavigateUrl is not a valid attribute of element 'LinkButton'. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use.

Change TextBox code with Link button

```
<asp: TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Data" Text='<%#Server.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Data"))) %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl='YouFolder/<%#Eval("DATA") %>' />/>
  </EditTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue i had html stored in my DB and wanted to show it in a div. This is what worked for me.

```
<itemTemplate>
 <div>
   <%# Server.HtmlDecode( (string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "notes") ) %>
 </div>
</itemTemplate>
```

Hopefully this will answer your problem ;)